# How to change keyboard shortcut for switching between windows of the same application?

Tags: unity, 14.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, compiz

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>|</kbd> to switch windows of the same application. How can I change this keyboard shortcut to something else? I have tried using `Gnome Control Center` under `System Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts->Navigation` and the CompizConfig Settings Manager (`ccsm`).

Answer (score 3):

The CompizConfig Settings Manager is the correct application to use to change this keyboard shortcut when you're using Compiz as your window manager.

Compiz has several plugins that can be used to switch between applications, and they all have a different look & feel:

1. Application Switcher
2. Ring Switcher
3. Shift Switcher
4. Static Application Switcher

In `ccsm`, you can enable or disable a plugin by using the little checkbox on the left of the plugin icon. Try the four switcher plugins above (always only enable one at a time to avoid conflicts) and decide which one you like best.

The *Application Switcher* plugin does not support (as far as I can see) switching windows of the same application. The other three plugins do, though: To change the keyboard shortcut for switching windows of the same application, click on the plugin icon that you are using and look for a setting like `Next/Previous Window Key (Group)`. Example for the `Shift Switcher`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I will test this now.. I have currently not enabled any of the switchers you mention above. So I wonder: why is this choice (`Next Window Key (Group)`) not listed under the Ubuntu Unity Plugin Switcher (in `ccsm->Desktop->Ubuntu Unity Plugin->Switcher`)

Comment: I tried the `Shift Switcher` with `Ctrl+|`.. And it did not work. First issue: the old keyboard shortcut is still working (`Alt+|`), second issue: The switcher is not working: I opened two windows of my web browser (chromium) and tried pressing `Ctrl+|`. One time the switcher opened but I could not change windows, and the other time Ubuntu crashed with an internal error..

Comment: Ok. First, try to use some keyboard shortcut that's not already in use. If there are conflicts, of course it is not surprising that this won't work as expected. Once you've made sure it works with some otherwise unused keyboard shortcut, you can try to set whatever shortcut you like and disable that shortcut elsewhere in order to get rid of conflicts. Second, don't start out with the Shift Switcher or the Ring Switcher. These have some fancy effects that may lead to those crashes on your system. Try the very simple *Static Application Switcher* first. :-)

Comment: Also, I'm not familiar with the Unity plugin for Compiz, so I can't tell you much about it. (I do use Compiz, but not Unity.) I *guess* that the Unity plugin implements (among other things) its own application switcher, whose shortcuts you can configure there, and which is completely unrelated to the other "standard" Compiz switcher plugins. This would explain why none of the other switchers were enabled for you. But you can certainly enable them anyway, and unset the application switcher shortcuts in the Unity plugin, so as to use a different (non-Unity) implementation of an app switcher.

Comment: Ok thanks for helping me out :). I still have problems. I disabled `Shift Switcher` then tested if `Ctrl+|` had any effect in my applications, to make sure that the shortcut was not already defined. Then I enabled `Static Application Switcher` with `Ctrl+|` for switching windows in same group. This worked for `gnome-terminal` windows, but not for Chromium, Emacs, and Okular windows..

Comment: I can confirm what you are seeing. This does not work with Chromium or Emacs. It does work, e.g., with Firefox. I am not sure which *window property* Compiz uses to identy windows of the same application. You can see window properties by issuing the command `xprop` and then clicking on a window. My first guess was that `WM_CLASS` is used. But then Chromium and Emacs should work. My second guess was that `_NET_WM_PID` is used (the process id). These do differ for Emacs windows, i.e., one Emacs window is one process. But for Chromium windows they are identical, so that can't be it either.

Comment: For such highly specific things, it may be better to ask in the Compiz forums, or to report a bug in the Compiz bug tracker (the behavior exhibited by *Previous/Next Window (Group)* is certainly not what most users would expect). I don't think there's an easy way for you to fix this. Well. You could think about having a look at KDE (instead of Unity) - I think that there this works perfectly ;)